# Ayuda con Url Amigable con parametro

Tags: reescritura-url

Estoy buscando ayuda con url amigables por el momento puedo acceder a las URL's de esta manera

www.midominio.com/demo-1
www.midominio.com/demo-8
www.midominio.com/demo-14

Este es mi codigo:

`RewriteRule ^demo-([0-9]+)/?$ ver.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Busco reemplazar la palabra "demo" en las url por mi url amigable, en este caso "zapatos-de-hombre,carteras-demujer,polos,etc" donde el ultimo numero es la variable:

**Busco Esto**

www.midominio.com/zapatos-de-hombre-color-verde-talla-42-1
www.midominio.com/polo-manga-larga-talla-35-8
www.midominio.com/zapatillas-de-mujer-talla-20-14

Comment: Mira patron MVC; el lenguaje no es problema toda vez que está saliendo esa forma para muchos lenguajes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción si lo que quieres es que te interprete cualquier cadena en lugar de "demo", usa `(.*)` en lugar de `demo`. Además, tendrías que cambiar el parámetro de `$1` a `$2`.

Así debería funcionarte:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+)/?$ ver.php?id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: gracias !! esto funciona...saludos!! que tenga buen dia